# Man walking on the rotating platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

The problem is:

> The solid cylindrical platform with mass $M$ and radius $R$ rotates with angular frequency $\omega$. On the edge of the platform there is a standing man with mass $m$. Then man begins to walk round the edge with velocity $v$ in the opposite direction of platform's rotation. And the task is to find new frequency $\omega '$.

So, I thought that the equation for this problem is

$$(I_{plat} + I_{man}) \  \omega = I_{plat} \  \omega ' + I_{man}\  (\omega ' - \frac{v}{R})$$
where $I$ is a moment of inertia. Equation is written in the inertial system.

But with this equation the result is like $\omega '  < 0$, so it begins to rotate in the opposite direction, it looks weird (with given values of parameters). And I was told that this equation is incorrect.

So, where did I do a mistake?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Is $\omega'$ supposed to be the new frequency of the _man_ or the _platform_? Your expression looks correct for the platform... And if the man walks at a velocity that cancels $\omega'$ exactly, the platform must be rotating much faster to carry all the angular momentum.  I don't see how $\omega'$ would go negative for positive $v$. Who told you that you were wrong?